# Ignore for accessibility with Google Maps compose SDK

Tags: google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, google-maps-markers, google-maps-compose

#### Background

I have a hybrid search in a production app that uses `google-maps-compose`'s `GoogleMap` composable. This search offers a bottom sheet that displays a list of results along with a map with pins. We would like to push visually impaired users to the bottom sheet results. To do this we need to make the `GoogleMap` composable unfocusable. This seems to be impossible. It absorbs focus even through other components.

#### Example

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun AccessibilityExample() {
    val markerStateSydney = remember { MarkerState(position = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)) }
    val markerStateTokyo = remember { MarkerState(position = LatLng(35.66, 139.6)) }

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetContent = {
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        color = Color.Gray,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 8.dp, topEnd = 8.dp),
                    )
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
            )
        },
    ) {
        GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clearAndSetSemantics { invisibleToUser() }
                .focusable(enabled = false)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Marker(
                state = markerStateSydney,
                title = "Marker in Sydney",
            )
            Marker(
                state = markerStateTokyo,
                title = "Marker in Tokyo"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

You can see here that the pin is focused through the bottom sheet.

[image: The pin is focusable through the bottom sheet]

#### What I have tried

I have tried all typical compose "ignore for accessibility" solutions to no avail. This includes:

- `Modifier.focusable(enabled = false)`
- `Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics {}`
- `Modifier.semantics { invisibleToUser() }`

There is an [issue](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/305) with the `google-maps-compose` sdk concerning this.

#### What I need

I would love any Google attention on this issue or any work arounds anyone has found. This work around can be particular to the `GoogleMap` composable or any ideas of how I might "steal" focus from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was impossible all along. The Google Maps Android Compose team recently released a fix for this. Check out [this comment](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/305#issuecomment-1789497277) to learn more.

Setting these two attributes results in the desired behavior.

```kotlin
GoogleMap(
    // mergeDescendants will remove accessibility from the entire map and content inside.
    mergeDescendants = true,
    contentDescription = null,
    ...
)
```

So with my example the solution would be:

```kotlin
private fun AccessibilityExample() {
    val markerStateSydney = remember { MarkerState(position = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)) }
    val markerStateTokyo = remember { MarkerState(position = LatLng(35.66, 139.6)) }

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetContent = {
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        color = Color.Gray,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 8.dp, topEnd = 8.dp),
                    )
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
            )
        },
    ) {
        GoogleMap(
            mergeDescendants = true,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Marker(
                state = markerStateSydney,
                title = "Marker in Sydney",
            )
            Marker(
                state = markerStateTokyo,
                title = "Marker in Tokyo"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answered my question too! Thank you!